# AWS Cognito: After new user logs in with temporary, use SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication, totp

I've created a user pool for our development environment, wherein I've made MFA required. Then I create a new user using `AdminCreateUser` where I pass the `phone_number` and `email` of the user.

The problem I'm facing is only during e2e Cypress tests. After the user is created, I'm able to login with the temporary password, but in the next step it takes me to the SMS_MFA challenge. I've no way to proceed further with `SMS_MFA` during e2e tests.

But if I had the option of setting up `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA` after setting the permanent password, that'd solve the problem for the e2e tests. For `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA`, I'm using an OTP generator NodeJS library which takes in the secret code and gives me an OTP.

Anyone know how can I setup `SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA` setting up permanent password in AWS Cognito?